# Get last edit location in gedit

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gedit, gedit-plugin

I want to write a gedit plugin that creates a shortcut to go to the last edit location. Therefore I wonder how to get this location in (py)GTK/gedit.

Edit: accessing the view (`GtkSourceView`) or the document (`GtkSourceBuffer`) is not a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "last edit location".  Where the cursor is?  Where something was most recently inserted or deleted?  Or something else?

Comment: I mean the place where "undo" would affect the document --> where something was most recently inserted or deleted

Comment: This question is really two parts: how to get the gtksourceview object from a plugin, and then how to track the last edit location in a gtksourceview.  For the former, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2283933  For the later, you should google or ask on SO about gtksourceview (or gtktextview, its super-class) to find the answer.